# which value cannot be determined

Tags: real-analysis

[image: ed]

I get A and C are both unobtainable. But there is supposed to be 1 correct answer. Not sure if I am being silly or it's the question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $7^2+7=56$, so $f(7)=f(56)$. I think you are correct.